# Motion of a bob in a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

A bob has been attached to a pendulum which is oscillating in a semi circular path. If the the bob gets torn at the lowest position(equilibrium position),then determine the equation of the motion of the path of the bob as it got torn.

In our book,the answer is given as $y=-cx^2$.But i dont understand what $x,y$ mean in this scenario?Also how did they derive this equation?

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using $y$ and $x$ in the standard sense of $x$ indicating horizontal position and $y$ as vertical position, where the origin $(0,0)$ is the position of the bob when the pendulum breaks. They are saying the bob will then follow a parabolic trajectory, since $y=-cx^2$ is a parabola. This is the trajectory of all projectiles in free fall that start with zero initial vertical velocity and a non-zero initial horizontal velocity.

In general for a projectile launched from point $(x_0,y_0)$ with a speed $v$ and angle from the horizonal $\theta$ the trajectory is described v by

$$y=y_0+\tan\theta\cdot(x-x_0)-\frac{g(x-x_0)^2}{2v^2\cos^2\theta}$$

which is obtainable from the parametric equations with respect to time for motion with constant acceleration $-g$ only in the vertical direction and no acceleration in the horizontal direction
$$y=y_0+v\sin\theta\cdot t-\frac12gt^2$$
$$x=x_0+v\cos\theta\cdot t$$

Comment: Could you please kindly explain that trajectory in details?Sorry if it is too obvious,i am quite new to these

Comment: @a_i_r Can you be more specific? Also the comments are not the place to tack on additional questions. Best to make a new post if you have new questions.

Comment: I meant why $y=-cx^2$ is the trajectory,sorry

Comment: @a_i_r I have added the relevant concepts. The work is up to you.

Comment: @a_i_r As BioPhysicist infers, you have to do the work. We'll help push you to the concepts, which has been done well.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know is that the bob is projected with a horizontal velocity as it got torn, therefore it is going in a parabolic trajectory. The standard equation of a parabola is $y=ax^2+bx+c$. As the parabola opens downward in your example, it has to be $a<0$. That's why the coefficient of $x^2$ in your equation is $-c$. According to your equation, they have chosen (0,0) coordinates as the initial position (or the equilibrium position). So the eqation is $y=-cx^2$ where $y$ is the vertical displacement up and $x$ is the horizontal displacement right (according to following image). Since you are considering displacement along positive $x$ and $y$ axes, you get a negative value for $y$. It has to be, because the bob is moving downwards with a negative vertical displacement up.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot,could you please check the last answer and the comments followed after that kindly?Regards

Comment: @a_i_r , Al Brown is right because $y$ is displacement up. As the bob moves downwards you get $y<0$.

Comment: If the bob moves downwards,how can $y$ be displacement up,shouldn't be displacement down?

Comment: For instance, if you are going towards the right, your displacement to the right is positive(with respect to a selected point), while the displacement to the left is negative.

Answer (score 0):

$y$ is the up direction and $x$ is the horizontal direction (with positive $x$ being the direction ball was moving when string cut).

$y= -cx^2$ is just the equation for a falling object that has a horizontal velocity, assuming no wind resistance so that horizontal velocity never changes as it falls. Only the constant c will be affected by the horizontal velocity.

Assume ball swinging to the right when cut. We know it’s traveling exactly horizontally because it’s cut at the bottom of the swing.

Symbols: $y$ is ball displacement up. $x$ is ball displacement right. $v_y$ is ball velocity up, $v_x$ is velocity right. $a_y$ and $a_x$ are acceleration. $g$ is the acceleration of gravity $9.8 \;\mathrm{m/s^2}$. t is time from cut.

This comes from $v_y = -g t$ (because falling always means $a_y = -g$, and we started at $v_y=0$ so change in vertical speed over time (which always equals $-g t$) equals speed over time, so that $y = -1/2 g t^2$ , and $v_x$ is a constant so that $x = v_x t$ or $t = x/v_x$.

If you sub that $t$ into the $y$ equation you get the result (remember $v_x$ is a constant),
$$y= -\frac{g}{(2 v_x^2)} x^2 = -c x^2$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer,a question, does y and x represent displacement?

Comment: Yes ,( and i need to write 12 characters for a comment...

Comment: @ a_i_r I edited to include definitions and a note

Comment: Ok done editing. Lemme know

Comment: Why did you consider $y$ as the displacement up?Here the bob is falling down,how can it have a displacement in the upward direction?Shouldn't then the equation be $y=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$?Also you said the bob travels horizontally,so shouldn't the value of $y$ be $0$ then?

Comment: When the rope is cut, it is cut when the ball is at the lowest point of the pendulum, at that exact moment it has only horizontal velocity, at that moment: t=0, y=0, x=0, vx>0 and vx never changes as it falls, ax=0, vy=0, ay=-g. Then from there since ay=-g, we will have vy=-gt and y= -1/2 gt^2 if y is up. All of that says it is moving to the right but not accelerating or decelerating in that direction, and it is not moving down yet but is accelerating downward and will be moving down. **That way $y= -c x^2$ will be true. If we picked y is down, then we would end up with $y= c x^2$ instead.**

Comment: But as you said the ball will be moving downwards,then displacement $y$ is negative and $g$ is negative as well,shouldn't the equation be then $-y=\frac{1}{2}(-g)t^2$?

Comment: If we **define** the variable y as “the amount of displacement up” then we have that anything above where we start will be y>0. That way, since the ball is falling, y will actually be a negative number. The left side of $-y = ...$ would be positive. -y is positive using our definition of y. But that right side $1/2(-g)t^2$ is negative. Therefore if y is up then $y=1/2(-g)t^2$. If we change our definition of y **AND** change the equation we use, then that would also work. **I guess both work**

Comment: @a_i_r does that explain? I think the distinction is between defining what a variable is as one thing, and then using it as another (like figuring out if it is positive or negative and how it works in an equation - *after* being defined a certain way).